How to detect touches outside a drop down menu to close it in react native
I wanted to use zeego for dropdown menus but since it lacks certain functioning in android I decided to drop the idea as I am developing an app primarily focussing on android. So I decided to make my own menu. This menu is present inside a ScreenHeader component that gets rendered as a header for a screen like below
<Stack.Screen
        options={{
          header: () => (
            <ScreenHeader
              title={
                typeof passwordTitle === "string" ? passwordTitle : "Password"
              }
              isDropDownMenuVisible={true}
              isBackBtnVisible={true}
              dropDownMenuList={DROPDOWN_MENU}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

ScreenHeader.tsx
  <View className={`flex-row h-[70px] items-center bg-black-200  px-3`}>
     // other code
      {isDropDownMenuVisible && <Menu buttons={dropDownMenuList} />}
    </View>

and the Menu component looks like this
const Menu = ({ buttons }: { buttons: PropsType[] }) => {
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    // some reanimate code

 
  return (
    <View className="relative">
      <TouchableOpacity
        className="p-1 flex-row items-center justify-center"
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        onPress={toggleMenu}
      >
        <Ionicons name="ellipsis-vertical" size={24} color="#F5F5F5" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {menuVisible && (
        <Animated.View
          style={[animatedStyle]}
          className="flex-col z-20 absolute rounded-md w-40 top-10 right-4 bg-[#2C2C2C] shadow-2xl"
        >
          {buttons.map((item) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={item.title}
              className="flex-row items-center space-x-4 p-4"
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            >
              {item.icon}
              <Text
                className={`${
                  item.type === "danger" ? "text-[#FF0000]" : "text-white-200"
                } text-2xl font-patrg`}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </Animated.View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

The toggling of the menu works as normal when the user click on the three dots. But now I want the user to be able to close the menu when he clicks anywhere outside the menu which is a usual feature in all apps. But since I am new to react native I have no idea how to do it. I looked up in chat gpt which suggested to me to use a Modal and touchablewithoutfeedback combination to do it but I do not think that this is how detecting touches outside the menu works in professional apps or UI librararies. Moreover using a Modal also messes up the positioning of the menu relative to the button.
So can anyone please suggest me how can I detect touches outside the menu to close it.

Keep your isDropDownMenuVisible state globally using Context Api or redux.
Wrap your app in TouchableWithoutFeedback and update state globally on press of it.
